# Mysql function that repalce .com/**** ignore with .com

Tags: mysql, function

is there a function in mysql that replace say my attribute is "URL"

if I use replace would be

```
REPLACE(URL,".com/index" , ".com")
```

but I want to be able to replace anything else after .com  -> ".com/*" with ".com" 
Is there an easy way I can do this using function ?

Comment: Read [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are many ways doing that. Here is one of them:

```
SELECT REPLACE(URL,SUBSTRING_INDEX(URL,'.com',-1) , "");
```

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(URL,'.com',-1)` will return the part after .com
Then `REPLACE` with empty string will delete it.